# PHP Merge PNG Images

Tags: php, image, png

How can i merge 2 png images, or a JPEG over a png? I have this image:
[image: This is the background png image]

The result would have to be like this:

[image: Result]

Is there a lightweight library that can do this, or is it possible with php functions? I just want to keep the overlay image withing the background (margin of 10px) - i like to integrate it into my api.. so i can create them on the fly - or store them for later, but being able to create/batch create them online.

Comment: Look up the GD and ImageMagick libraries. GD is more commonly used. ImageMagick is more powerful. Both will be capable of overlaying pictures. However there's a *lot* of detail missing in your question. For example, do you actually need the images combined, or would it be better simply to display them layered on top of each other on the page? Do you even need images; if your background image is just a border with rounded corners, why not use an HTML border? What should the layering do if there is more to the background than plain white? What about transparency on the foreground image?

Comment: Well i provide XMLTV EPG TV guides, and in the XMLTV files is room for icons. So when  use the guide, you will have station icons. Now i have a good collection of icons - but i add new stations every week, and creating these images takes some time, uploading them etc. So i thought would be easier to do it from the admin panel - online, instead of on my desktop and then uploading through ftp..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) PHP library, more specifically the [insert function](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert).

From the documentation:

> Paste a given image source over the current image with an optional position and a offset coordinate. This method can be used to apply another image as watermark because the transparency values are maintained.

And an example:

```
// create new Intervention Image
$bg = Image::make('public/background.jpg');


// create a new Image instance for inserting
$logo = Image::make('public/logo_discovery.png');

// Insert the logo onto the background
$bg->insert($logo, 'center');
```

Comment: Thank you, only problem with this is - i dont have laravel or composer. So i dont know if it works without / or how to use it without these..

Comment: Hmm, I don’t know how to use it without [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Maybe you could use the [source code](https://github.com/Intervention/image) directly? If you haven’t used Composer before, I’d definitely recommend you check it out.

Comment: I havent used it "yet".. i didnt need it yet, but i will check it out thanks

Comment: Re "don't have laravel or composer" -- Honestly, if you're doing PHP without Composer, then you're making things much harder for yourself than you need to. Composer is very easy to learn and use, and once you're using it, it makes PHP about a gazillion times easier to work with.